# Работа с трёхмерным массивом

Tags: c++, массивы

Как эффективнее создать алгоритм?
Задаётся двумерный массив, скажем размером а*б. и эти самые а и б уже никогда не изменятся больше. Создаю трёхмерный массив, у которого первый индекс бывает только 0.
Над этим массивом проводятся некоторые вычисления, на их основе создаётся новый массив а*б.
На этом моменте мне нужно добавить ещё один массив размером а*б, а первый индекс трёхмерного массива сможет быть 0 и 1, и так дальше, пока не будет найден "правильный" массив размером а*б. сохранять предыдущие состояния нужно затем, что к ним часто придётся возвращаться.
Выделяю память в начале через malloc, а дальше изменяю размер через realloc. Я так понимаю, что realloc на самом деле ищет место в памяти нужного размера, затем копирует предыдущий массив в новое место, а старую память очищает. В моём случае массив часто будет расти, а значит постоянно нужно будет тратить время на перенос данных из одного участка памяти в другой. Есть другой способ провернуть всё это, чтобы не перемещать данные? Угадать/вычислить заранее кол-во требуемой памяти невозможно даже примерно, максимальный первый индекс запросто может быть и только 0 и 100500, всё зависит от вводимых данных в первый массив а*б размера.

Comment: Ну, я бы использовал в качестве двумерного массива, скажем, `std::vector<std::vector...` или `std::array<...`, и вектор таких массивов, постепенно наращивая их количество с помощью `push_back`.

Comment: Во-первых, в С++ есть только одномерные массивы. Т.е. ваш вопрос должен звучать навроде "выбор оптимального размещения многомерных данных в памяти". Во-вторых добавление еще одного массива не обязательно подразумевает копирование всех предыдущих куда-то там. В третьих `realloc` в С++ не стоит использовать.

Comment: @VTT realloc именно что подразумевает перенос данных с помощью копирования. Вне зависимости от формулировки, я написал выше, что мне нужно сделать достаточно подробно, но без лишних деталей. Если есть вариант с другим я.п., предлагайте, мне не критично именно С++ использовать.

Comment: Вы скорее описали, что *не нужно* делать. Для общего случая имеется библиотечная реализация массива динамической длины - `::std::vector`.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать динамические таблицы. Каждый раз когда Вам нужно расширить ваш массив, удваивайте его размеры.

Comment: @Harry сделал vector<vector<vector<unsigned char>>> ar; и это сработало. Как правильно сделать push_back() туда, чтобы в "верхний уровень" vector добавить первый элемент vector<vector<unsigned char>>?

Comment: Ну просто создать нужный `vector<vector<unsigned char>>` и `push_bak` его в тот самый внешний вектор...

Comment: @Harry жаль, что нет варианта проще. Выходит, тут список списков списков, причём в каждом вложенном списке может быть разное количество вложенных элементов. "Прямоугольный" массив был бы проще в понимании.

Comment: Если вас пугает изменяемый размер вектора - воспользуйтесь, как я и писал, `std::array`, в нем размер, как и в обычном массиве, задается во время компиляции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментарий код не воткнешь нормально...

Вот что предлагал я, если размеры 2d фиксированы:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int ROWS = 5, COLS = 8;

using Matrix = array<array<int,COLS>,ROWS>;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<Matrix> a(1);

    for(size_t r = 0; r < ROWS; ++r)
    {
        for(size_t c = 0; c < ROWS; ++c)
        {
            a[0][r][c] = r+c;
        }
    }

    //....

    Matrix b;
    for(size_t r = 0; r < ROWS; ++r)
    {
        for(size_t c = 0; c < ROWS; ++c)
        {
            b[r][c] = r*c;
        }
    }

    a.push_back(b);
}
```

Comment: vector в итоге оказался удобнее. через pop_back и push_back очень удобно удалять/добавлять элементы, а через size получать размер. мне не нужно запускать цикл и считать все не равные нолю элементы, достаточно size(), а доступ к последнему не равному нолю элементу через back() -- очень удобно по сравнению с обычными массивами. какие ограничения меня могут ждать при использовании vector? сейчас мой алгоритм легко считает маленькие "таблицы", но с большими выдаёт ошибку как название этого сайта если использовать рекурсию, а если через while, то просто работает бесконечно.

Comment: И кто писал вот это? *жаль, что нет варианта проще. Выходит, тут список списков списков, причём в каждом вложенном списке может быть разное количество вложенных элементов. "Прямоугольный" массив был бы проще в понимании* Блин, вы уж определились бы сначала, что вам нужно! Я с самого начала вам написал - *я бы использовал в качестве двумерного массива, скажем, `std::vector<std::vector...` или `std::array<...`, и вектор таких массивов* - но вам же не понравилось. Переделал - нет, опять не так, надо, как было. Как говорят, совет просят, чтоб сделать наоборот - это точно... :(

Comment: для моей задачи vector оказался гораздо лучшим вариантом, чем обычный массив. Отличный совет был.

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующим образом создание массива 1,w,v:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned char w = 5, v = 4;
    vector<vector<vector<unsigned char>>> ar;
    ar.assign(1,vector<vector<unsigned char>>(w,vector<unsigned char>(v,0)));
    return 0;
}
```